# mobile number formatting using python code

Tags: python, api, formatting, twilio

Add country code into the excel sheets of mobile numbers using python..

for i in range(0,10):
input=contactList.MobileNumber[i]
phone_number=client.lookups.v1.phone_numbers(contactList.MobileNumber[i]).fetch(country_code='US')

print(phone_number.phone_number)

output:=

7329257123
2019544156
9518285268
7329257143
7323181712
7322268445
9082965185
8482562756
6094235467
7328958604
+17328958656

i want to get full list of numbers with country code but only getting last number, dont able to understand what is the erroe in the above code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong in the question. And it's likely that the cause of the problem is that the indentation is wrong in your original code. From your description,  the`print()`  call is outside the `for`-loop, and should be inside it. Python is picky about indentation, and so are Python programmers.

Comment: Hi if i am passing a list of number using excel  and i want to format those numbers by adding country code in front of them how can i do that with python.